# Boostrap 3 navbar collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't for the life of me figure out why my navbar won't collapse.  I bring in the normal bootstram js and css file along with the transition and collapse js files.  Here is my code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand">LandingExample</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submit Form</a></li> 
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html">Contact Us</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        <li><img class="product-select-logo" width = "34.8" height="38.4" src="http://static.hsappstatic.net/style_guide/static-8.123/img/logos/hubspot/sprocket-64.png"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: On 4th line of your code, write `data-target="#myNavBar"` ( note the "B" in uppercase ).  Because, on the 11th line, you wrote the ID of the div as `myNavBar`.

Comment: YES! thank you!  Great catch.  God I have such a love/hate relationship with code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why some people use List tags in Nav bars when you don't need them. Anyway, here's a HTML5 collapsing menu technique you may like:

```
<nav style="position:absolute; left:20px; top:50px;">

<div onclick="TheBox.removeAttribute('open');">

<details id="TheBox"><summary>Choices</summary>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Home</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">About</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Products</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Services</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="">Contact</a>

</details></div></nav>
```

Comment: I took the basics of my navbar from w3schools maybe that is why people use them.

Comment: This comes out to be more of just a dropdown list then collapsing a navbar

Comment: What's the difference? :)

Comment: I guess the difference is my lack of bootstrap knowledge and how I can implement that into my nav

Comment: If you want the menu OPEN by default use this line isntead... <details id="TheBox" open>

Answer (score 0):

please use this html.. i think ur problem is solve..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LandingExample</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Submit Form</a></li> 
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html">Contact Us</a></li> 
    </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="./fallpage.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        <li><img class="product-select-logo" width = "34.8" height="38.4" src="http://static.hsappstatic.net/style_guide/static-8.123/img/logos/hubspot/sprocket-64.png"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```